# How to group repeated characters by number of the times those got repeated?

Tags: javascript

Objective:

Load a variable with a string value with random characters, split each character into an array, sort those alphabetically and also made them in upper case format. At end, it's required print the number times each character was repeated and store the results into a new variable in a string data.

Example:

```
const randomChars = 'ABaaBCDdeGFAAR';
```

Desired Output:

> 5A 2B 1C 2D 1E 1F 1G 1R

My attempt to solve the problem:

```
// convert string to uppercase:
let upperChars = randomChars.toUpperCase();
// convert characters into array:
let splitChars = upperChars.split("");
// order the chars by alphabetic order in the array:
let sortChars = splitChars.sort();
```

Now I am stuck the part where I have to group the characters, any idea how can I solve this?

Is there anyway to ignore the white space in the split function in case some string has space in between characters? ex: "ASdj asd asADASD"

Comment: You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can add +10 points to any author of any good answer by click upper gray triangl

Answer (score 2):

Try (we use characters as keys in h={} and count them)

```js
const randomChars = 'ABaaBCDdeGFAAR';

let h= {};
randomChars.toUpperCase().split('').forEach(c => h[c]=++h[c]||1);
let r = Object.keys(h).sort().map(k => h[k]+k).join(' ');

console.log(r);
```

Comment: This is a good enough approach but I have to ask - why is it written like code golf? Seems to me that using single letters for everything isn't exactly the most useful learning tool.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Map`

```
const randomChars = 'ABaaBCDdeGFAAR';
let result = new Map();
for(let letter of randomChars.toUpperCase().sort().replace(/ /,'').split('')) {
    if (result.has(letter)) {
        result.set(letter, result.get(letter)+1);
    } else {
        result.set(letter, 1);
    }
}
let str = ""
for(let pair of result) {
     str += pair.join('')
}
console.log(str)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use reduce method , check the below code

```js
        const randomChars = 'ABaaBCDdeGFAAR';
        // convert string to uppercase:
        
        let upperChars = randomChars.toUpperCase();
        // convert characters into array:

        let splitChars = upperChars.split("");
        // order the chars by alphabetic order in the array:
        
        let sortChars = splitChars.sort();

        let output = sortChars.reduce((acc, val) => {
            acc[val] = (typeof acc[val] === 'undefined') ? 1 : acc[val] + 1;
            return acc;
        }, {})

        let result = [];
        for (key in output) {
            result.push(output[key] + key)
        }


        alert(result.join(' '))
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using reduce with Object.entries

1. Split string with '' and use reduce to loop string
2. Convert each character to upper case and count each character into accumulator obj
3. Use Object.entries to join count with character

```js
const randomChars = 'ABaaBCDdeGFAAR';
let obj = randomChars.split('').reduce((acc,v)=> {
  v = v.toUpperCase();
  acc[v] = acc[v]?acc[v] +1 : 1;
  return acc
}, {})
//{A: 5, B: 2, C: 1, D: 2, E: 1, F: 1, G: 1, R: 1}

console.log(Object.entries(obj).map((v) => v[1] + v[0]))
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/LYPNBrW

**Option2:** Using one loop to find count of characters using reduce and Object.values

1. 1. Split string with '' and use reduce to loop string
2. Convert each character to upper case and count each character into accumulator obj
3. Use Object.values to get count with character

```js
const randomChars = 'ABaaBCDdeGFAAR';
let obj = randomChars.split('').reduce((acc,v)=> {
  v = v.toUpperCase();
  acc[v] = acc[v]? (parseInt(acc[v]) +1)+v : 1+v
  return acc
}, {})
//{A: "5A", B: "2B", C: "1C", D: "2D", E: "1E", F: "1F", G: "1G", R: "1R"}
console.log(Object.values(obj))
```

codepen- https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/QWLNBxo?editors=1010